# Stop executing the rest of the code when condition is met within if statement

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

How can I jump to a textbox if the user left it empty. The if-else I used displays the message box but still continues the rest of the code.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("enter word to search for")
    End If
    WebBrowser1.Hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("enter word to search for")
    TextBox1.Focus()
    Exit Sub
End If
WebBrowser1.Hide()
```

Comment: I would also be inclined to set the focus back to the text box as you want the user to enter some text, have edited answer (I hope!) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `WebBrowser1.Hide()` on the else statement 
Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("enter word to search for")
    Else
         WebBrowser1.Hide()
    End If
```

or you can use an `Exit Sub`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("enter word to search for")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    WebBrowser1.Hide()
```